# Link checker in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, net-http

I have the following stored in a rake task. Basically I need it update the "published" attribute to 0 from 1 if the response code from the url is not 200. When I run this take I get: `undefined method 'request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x00000102136408 URL:url>`

```
desc "Problem products"
task :update_broken_links => :environment do
  require 'net/http'

  Product.find(:all, :conditions =>["published = ? AND feed_id = ?", '1', 820]).each do |product|
    url = product.url 
    uri = URI('url')
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    x = response.code.to_i    

    if x != 200
      published = '0'
    else
      published = product.published
    end


    product.update_attribute(:publsihed, publsihed) 

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have `uri = URI('url')` you need to change it to `uri = URI(url)`. Your current code is trying to convert the string `'uri'` into a URI instead of using the contents of the `uri` variable.

You'll also run into a problem near the end at `product.update_attribute(:publsihed, publsihed)` once you get there. You've got a typo: 'publsihed' instead of 'published'.